# reduce network latency in remote db connection postgresql 9.5

Tags: python, postgresql, server

I have flask application running with gunicorn and postgresql 9.5 database.
Due to postgresql high cpu usage , the database was migrated to remote.(DigitalOcean) . The result was that my celery periodic computation tasks time increased from avg 4min to 10min.
So i figure that it must be due to network latency.
Is there anything that can be done to improve this?

Comment: Could you move the app to digital ocean?

Comment: Analyze where the problem is. Perhaps you are running too many small queries rather than fewer big ones? Lazy loading?

Comment: @StephenPaulger app is also on DO

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe db query optimisations is what i will go into. but i just wanted to know whether there can be some improvement before that.. maybe some postrges.conf setting or something.